# How do I remove only the top part of a box-shadow?

Tags: border, css

I'm using `border-radius` and `box-shadow` to make a glow around an element.

Can I remove only the top part of the `box-shadow`?

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/kL8tR/1/)

```
div {
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    z-index: -10;
    padding: 26px 24px 46px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #000; /*#fff;*/
    border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(200,200,200,0.7) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
     -khtml-box-shadow: rgba(200,200,200,0.7) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
       -moz-box-shadow: rgba(200,200,200,0.7) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
            box-shadow: rgba(200,200,200,0.7) 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

Edit: this little thingy is the problem!
[image]

Comment: Here's a wholly unproffesional and ugly solution that should be used by nobody, and works: http://jsfiddle.net/kL8tR/55/ I just hid the top border under an absolutely positioned black element.

Comment: It is not covering the entire top-border. On wide screen - only half of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works, but I'll admit to not knowing if there's a better way (or if it's possible without adding a wrapper element). Using multiple `box-shadow`s would be a good idea, but I can't seem to make it look the same.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/8qEUc/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bla">
    <div> something </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bla {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0 -10px
}
#bla > div {
    /* the CSS from your question here */
}
```

Comment: +1 because it works well, though I am surprised there is no pure css way to do this consistently.

Comment: I believe @kizi's solution achieves exactly the same effect more elegantly than this one and is pure CSS. Give it a look.

Comment: @Robin Winslow: Yeah, @kizu's solution (+1) and your variations on it are definitely closer than the other answers. However, they're not "perfect" like mine is (though obviously mine has horrible HTML, and has the disadvantage of screwing with `margin`). Comparison: http://i.stack.imgur.com/89In6.png. I'm probably being too picky, and often it won't have to work on a gradient (or otherwise variable) background.

Comment: @Robin Winslow: Amusingly enough, I just noticed something wrong with my own answer - in Firefox it's cutting off the shadow too early. Fortunately, it can easily be fixed by adjusting the `5px` number. That's what I get for not testing with Firefox back when I posted my answer!

Comment: overflow hidden is creating problem for me so Ive used @Kizu's solution.

Answer (score 15):

Since you use box-shadow, you can use pseudo-element to create it and place under your div, placing it so only the needed parts would be visible: http://jsfiddle.net/kL8tR/60/

There are some important notes:

- The pseudo-element must have `z-index: -1`
- The div itself must have `position: relative` and no `z-index`

Pseudo-elements + CSS3 = awesomeness :)

Comment: I like this solution, it's more elegant. Although I don't think you need `z-index: -1`: http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/kL8tR/61/. `:before` doesn't work in IEs < 8 - http://caniuse.com/#search=:before - but as you say we're using `box-shadow` anyway - http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow.

Comment: If you want an effect more like @thirtydot's, simply expand the `:before` element: http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/kL8tR/62/

Answer (score 11):

@milo; is not your top border it's a `shadow` which you give in your code

for removing top glow you have to define vertical spacing of your shadow.

Write this in your shadow css:

```
box-shadow:0 3px 6px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 6px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 6px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
-khtml-box-shadow:0 3px 6px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
```

& your can generate from here http://css3generator.com/

NOTE: there are four properties of shadow are `horizontal, vertical, blur & spread`
for inside shadow you can define `inset` for it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/kL8tR/59/. That's probably close enough, but it's not perfect. The top part of the `box-shadow` is still faintly visible, and the rounded corners at the top don't *quite* look right (in Chrome at least).

Answer (score 4):

you could just shift the shadow lower down (vertical displacement) and reduce the shadow radius, something along the lines of (replace the asterisk with the amount of pixels needed to *just* cover the top shadow with the box itself):

```
box-shadow: 0 *px 10px 0 rgba(200,200,200,0.7);
```

Comment: plus, it's all css with nothing really complicated

Answer (score 2):

If you use a negative spread radius and calibrate the other parameters to suit what your looking for it should give you the desired effect.

[CSS Box Shadow Negative Radius Spread](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/#article-header-id-4)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px -6px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. My method **only uses CSS**.

**Example Link :** http://jsfiddle.net/kL8tR/56/

```
div{
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 45px;

    padding: 26px 24px 46px;

    border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-top: none;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px black,  0px -20px black, 0px 1px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px black,  0px -20px black, 0px 1px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px black,  0px -20px black, 0px 1px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);

}
```

Basically what I am doing, I am creating multi-layer shadows, so the first shadow overlays the second layer, masking the top section.

**I have used this before, here is my reference :**

Look under section - Layering multiple shadows [ http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/ ]

Comment: That looks perfect on a solid background, but not so good otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/kL8tR/58/

Comment: +1 because it works in this scenario. Though as @thirtydot says, it is rather limited given the background needs to be a solid colour.

Comment: @Marc Uberstein why you remove the border radius?!?

Comment: The question was How to remove the top-border, that was my main focus. [BTW no need to down vote my answer]