# HTML/CSS - Fixed page borders with scrollable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to format my webpage so i can have a `border-left` and `border-right`. I want to have the border take up 100% of the page height even if the content on the page does not.

I have been able to achieve this but, if content on the page exceeds 100% of the page height and the user must scroll, then the border does not fill the extra height on the page.

How can I fix this with CSS?

I am using Ruby on Rails, and I am adding my CSS to the `application.html.erb` file like so:

```
<body>
   <div=borders>
      <%= yield %>
   </div>
</body>

<style>
   .borders {
      padding-top: 2%;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
      padding-bottom: 5%;

      height: 100%;
      border-left: 120px solid #808080;
      border-right: 120px solid #808080;
   }
</style>
```

This is an example from one of the pages on my site of what it looks like currently:

[image]

If i remove the `height: 100%;` then the border will only fill as far as the page on the content goes. So if only 10% of the page is used then that is as far as the border goes. Like so:
[image]

Comment: Could you show the actual html that is produced at <div=borders>?

Comment: Sorry Cody, couldn't help you... `:(`

Comment: try this: `html, body, .borders { height: 100%; }`

Comment: @Aziz adding `.borders { height: 100% }` does not fix the issue. This makes the border reach 100% of the page, but no further. Meaning if you must scroll down, all the content below has no border. 
And `html, body { height: 100% }` just does nothing in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue here is overflow. When content is bigger than 100% of viewport, the borders will not continue because they are "capped" at 100%.

You could either use `overflow: auto` or replace `height: 100%` in `.borders { ... }` to `min-height: 100%;`

Of course for percentage height to work, you must have HTML and Body with 100% height defined (`html, body { height: 100%; }`).

**Working Example:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.borders {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border-left: 120px solid #808080;
  border-right: 120px solid #808080;
}

.borders div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borders">
  <div>long text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. the `min-height` was exactly what i needed. In combination with the `html, body` portion. 

Any chance you know how to add a drop shadow? I would like the White portion of the page, where it touches the gray border, to have a black drop shadow on the left and right of the page.

Comment: @CodyPritchard In that case I would recommend getting rid of the borders all together and making the body background gray while the `.borders` container is centered with `margin: 0 auto` and has a percentage width. That way you can use the CSS `box-shadow` property without any problems: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/pto819xn/1/

Comment: Thanks again. That did the trick. I just need to remove the top portion of the `box-shadow` now

Comment: @CodyPritchard you won't see it if you add `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` however, more answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024517/how-do-i-remove-only-the-top-part-of-a-box-shadow

Comment: Yes i have the `margin: 0; padding: 0;` but that does not solve it. The best way i found which works was adding a vertical off set matching the radius of the box shadow like so: `box-shadow: 0px 50px 50px black;`. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Is there a css way of scrolling the text inside the dotted border, without scrolling the border itself?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<body style="height: 100%">
  <div class="border">
  </div>
</body>
```

With CSS3 :

```
.border{ 
 ...
 height : 100vh;
  ...
 }
```